# React: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-html-parser'

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install `react-html-parser` in my docker container 'client':

```
docker-compose.yml
client/
      Dockerfile-dev
      node_modules/
      src/   
         components/
                   Seeds.jsx
```

and try and import it here:

**Seeds.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 }
from 'react-html-parser';
import axios from 'axios';
```

`'axios'` and `'react'` are instaled allright, but not `'react-html-parser'`. Console logs me the error:

```
index.js:1437 ./src/components/Seeds.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-html-parser' in '/usr/src/app/src/components'
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "react-html-parser":"^2.0.2", # <---------NEW
    "spotify-web-api-js": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
# base image
FROM node:11.6.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json

RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.2 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  client:
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL=${REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}
    depends_on:
      - web
```

I can'f find the module inside my `node_modules` folder...

what am I missing here?

---

**EDIT**: npm install without --silent:

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: Way too old
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.4: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js-pure@3.1.3 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: Have you taken the --silent off your npm install just to see if the install is logging out any errors?

Comment: Yes I had, please refer to my edit.

Comment: Are you launching this via a `docker-compose.yml`; and if you are, does it declare an anonymous volume for your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: yes, via docker-compose. please refer to edit for details. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your `docker-compose.yml` file says:

```
volumes:
  - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

You're telling Docker your `node_modules` directory contains critical data that needs to be persisted across container runs.  The first time you launch the container it will get populated from the image, but because that directory contains critical data, Docker will never ever update it again, even if you try to `npm install` additional modules.

For a near-term workaround, it's enough to `docker-compose stop; docker-compose rm; docker-compose up --build` your containers.  Deleting the existing container (and its anonymous volume) is important.

Comment: is your workaround required for all services under compose or only `client`?

Comment: Only the service where you specifically need to delete the anonymous volumes.  (You might consider whether you can remove these volume declarations altogether, because your code isn't data; it should be in the image you build.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I.love.you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `npm i react-html-parser --force`

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to why this would solve the problem?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 